# Adding button in php loop

Tags: php, mysql

as you can see in my code there is $url2 = 1
but i want to change $url2 value in loop and i did it.BUT in this loop the last loop value is set to $url2. in this case $url =3,
but i want button that when i chick it the $url2 value change as in loop
ex. when i click button1 $url2 =1;    button2 $url2 =2;     button3 $url2 =3;

this is what i want.

**php**

```
 <?php
    include('database_connection.php');
    $url2 = "1";
    $query = "SELECT count(product_id) AS product_id FROM product";  
        $statement1 = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement1->execute();
        $result1 = $statement1->fetchAll();
        $total = $result1[0]['product_id'];
        $pages = ceil($total / 5);
        for($i = 1; $i<= $pages; $i++) :           
        $url2 = $i;     
        ?>         
           <form method="post">
           <input type="submit" name="hello"
           class="button" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />      
           </form>        
     <?php
       endfor; 
     ?>
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you want the value of the PHP variable `$url2` to change when you click a button?

Comment: yes sir exactly.

Comment: Well, in that case you need to perform a request (either a form submission or AJAX). But since you already have a form in there, I doubt this is your actual problem. What are you trying to achieve with this change of `$url2` value? What should the program do based on that value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
 <?php
    include('database_connection.php');
    $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1 ;
    $query = "SELECT count(product_id) AS product_id FROM product";  
        $statement1 = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement1->execute();
        $result1 = $statement1->fetchAll();
        $total = $result1[0]['product_id'];
        $pages = ceil($total / 5);
        for($i = 1; $i<= $pages; $i++) :           
     ?>         
        <a class="button btn-sm" href="product.php?page=<?=$i>" ><?= $i ?></a>  
     <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: i want the value of the PHP variable $url2 to change when i click a button